# I cannot Manipulate this image how I need it to be using HTML or CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I can't center the image inside of the `<div class="cover">` tag.  It shows up but I cannot manipulate it in any way using style inside of the HTML file or inside of the CSS file and I need help.  Is there a way to be able to center the image and place the text over the image in the center.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Taniti-Tourism-Prototype\CSS\Homepage.css"/>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="cover"><a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Taniti-Tourism-Prototype\CSS\cover.jpg"></a>
  <div class="cover-text">
   <h1>This is Taniti</h1>
   <p>Welcome to Taniti</p>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
 .cover img{
 background-position:center;
}

.cover-text {
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 top:80%;
 left:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
 color:black;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is that what you want ???**

I added the image link to test the code correctly

```css
 .cover {
    position: absolute;
}
 
 .cover img{
 background-position:center;
}

.cover-text {
 text-align:center;
 position: relative;
 top:80%;
 left:50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -188%);
 color:black;
 }
```

```html
<body>

<body>

 <div class="cover"><a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRxvCs-MaY-woSG3atnjJiQ_Q3DjvFo-9k5erACjOGEVPwd2aGH&s"></a>
  <div class="cover-text">
   <h1>This is Taniti</h1>
   <p>Welcome to Taniti</p>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>

</body>
</html>
```

i have added to the css file
Class cover and i add

`position: absolute;`

Then
In `.cover-text` class
i modify the position from absolute to relative
You can control the exact location of the text from

```
 transform: translate (-50%, -188%);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are following the hard approach. an easier way to do this is to set the image as the background of the container (div), with the text being inside the container.

Also, make sure to set all child tags to `position: relative;` This way you can move everything inside the container without worrying to adjust the background. because you did already using CSS

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>This is Taniti</h1>
            <p>Welcome to Taniti</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
div{
    background-image: url(cover.jpg);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 400px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

h1, p {
    position:relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `background-position` for CSS backgrounds.

You can use the image as CSS background by using `background-image`.
Since we don't want the image to repeat itself, we'll add `background-repeat` aswell.
To center the image, we use `background-position`.

```
.cover {
  background-image: url('cover.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

---

To center the cover-text, we need to tell what surface to cover.
We can do this by adding a relative `position` to the cover-div.

```
.cover {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can't use `background` css properties on `<img>` tags, you will need to style the image another way.

Why not make use of `object-fit:cover`?

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.cover{
  width:100vw;
  height:75vh;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.cover img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
}
.cover-text{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  font-size:3.333vw;
}
```

```html
 <div class="cover"><a href="#"><img src="https://www.naturehills.com/media/catalog/product/cache/35c1080e597d6a74b42d0d88ced836c1/f/u/fuji-apple-tree-800x800.jpg"></a>
  <div class="cover-text">
   <h1>This is Taniti</h1>
   <p>Welcome to Taniti</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

You need to give the image container a position of `relative` and then `absolute` the image with your `object-fit:cover` and with a `width` and `height` of `100%`.

Flex the alignment of the text, `display:flex` and adjust the content div accordingly. `color:white;`

---

Sadly you will need to use a 'polyfill' for Internet Exploder but there are plenty out there https://github.com/jonathantneal/fitie

Comment: but how can i make this work with a navigation bar where i dont want the image to go over the nav bar

Comment: put the navigation bar as `position:fixed` and set the `z-index` to a high number. google: “fixed navigation bar”

Answer (score 0):

Make the entire container an anchor tag:

```css
.cover {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.cover img {
  width: 100%;
}

.cover .cover-text {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
  position: absolute;
}

.cover-text .h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 21px 0;
}

.cover-text .p {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<a class="cover" href="#">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/300">
  <span class="cover-text">
   <span class="h1">This is Taniti</span>
  <span class="p">Welcome to Taniti</span>
  </span>
</a>
```